# A galaxy with stars, milkyway and other stuffs (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What is a "realistic" way to build a galaxy in 2D with WPF?

I'm not interessed in the physical modelling but the graphical aspect **with WPF controls/effects**. At least the stars (position, size, color, pulsing etc.) should be generated from code. Generating milkyways would be nice. (See update bellow.)

Main questions are:

- **Stars**: lens flare? texturing?
- **Milkyway**: bump mapping?
- **"Far" stars**: textures? generated?
- **Pulsing**?
- other elements, any effects are welcome!

Some examples (taken from the web, I want to build similar pictures (animations) with wpf):

[image]

[image]

### Update

The goal of this project is to visualize huge data structures. "Galaxy" is only a semblance.

From birdview it's similar to [code_swarm](http://www.michaelogawa.com/code_swarm/) but based on WPF. So this is *not* an astronomy application or something, just a view for hierarchical data.

Comment: That top one's not a Galaxy, it's Bubble Art.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to create this beautiful nebulae. It is challenging task for professional artists to do manually ;)

Answer (score 3):

- Background stars: use one or two "star patch" images, and splatter them around in the background, with random angles, in random positions, and flipping them horizontally and vertically. Sample: http://www.sea-of-memes.com/LetsCode4/LetsCode4.html
- Foreground stars: use 5-15 'flare' pre-made gray-scale textures (1 per size) and colorize them slightly so each star has its own hue.
- Nebulae: Generate a random rectangular texture with [perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise). The alpha must also be controlled by the perlin noise, so the image is transparent in some spots. Make them big and fade the borders, so they are seamless. Each nebulae must be colorized. Experiment putting very faint, big nebulae in the background, so the space isn't completely black in all places.
- Galaxies: Same as the nebulae, except that with much less alpha, and the border fading is less gradual and more "oval" in shape.

I don't recommend pulsing. If you want to add some animation, simulate movement by adding different scroll levels (so the objects that are far away don't move at all, but the ones near the camera move more)

Oh and also:

- Put a link to the result here :)

Comment: With respect to the different scrolling speeds, you'll want to look into "Parallax scrolling" for more information (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling)

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, but I would like to use embeded WPF features to archive this. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know WPF myself, but I'm sure it is possible; It can be done in OpenGL and D3D, and it seems WPF can host context for both (just google OpenGL WPF or D3D WPF). I'd start by creating one such contexts inside a WPF window. Once you have that, you just have to use regular OpenGL or D3D calls to render whatever you want. It will probably use the graphics card automatically, if there's any.